# Splunk Truncated Date Comparison

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following Splunk search where I have Search results working with tokens from another Dashboard. I am trying to compare the truncated date of DAY but I can not get it to work properly.

```
MY SEARCH | eval Status = if(isnull(REJECT_REASON), "No Status", REJECT_REASON) 
| eval DATE_UPDATED = strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval DAY = strftime(_time, "%b %d, %Y") 
| stats values(MEMBER_NBR) as MEMBER_NBR, 
latest(Status) as STATUS, values(DATE_SENT) as "DATE_SENT", 
max(DATE_UPDATED) as DATE_UPDATED by CORRELATIONID
|where STATUS = if("$tok_status$"="", STATUS, "$tok_status$") 
and MEMBER_NBR = if("$tok_member$"="ALL", MEMBER_NBR, "$tok_member$") 
and DAY = if("$tok_day$"="ALL", DAY, "$tok_day$")
|sort limit=0 CORRELATIONID, DATE_UPDATED asc
```

In my where clause STATUS and MEMBER_NBR are working fine but now that I added DAY, there are no search results returned.

The token for "tok_day" is coming in as:

```
form.tok_day=Mar%2020%2C%202024
```

[image]

Comment: Does the data in the index contain a `DAY` field that looks exactly like $tok_day$, including the URL encoding?  I suspect the token must be unencoded before it can be compared to the data.

Comment: @RichG you're probably right but what gets me is that the ````tok_day```` token does properly populate the drop down I have in the drill down dashboard. How do I force the token to not encode with the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the token came to be encoded (perhaps it was the result of a drilldown), but a workaround is to decode the token before using it.

```
MY SEARCH | eval Status = if(isnull(REJECT_REASON), "No Status", REJECT_REASON) 
| eval DATE_UPDATED = strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval DAY = strftime(_time, "%b %d, %Y") 
| stats values(MEMBER_NBR) as MEMBER_NBR, 
latest(Status) as STATUS, values(DATE_SENT) as "DATE_SENT", 
max(DATE_UPDATED) as DATE_UPDATED by CORRELATIONID
|where STATUS = if("$tok_status$"="", STATUS, "$tok_status$") 
and MEMBER_NBR = if("$tok_member$"="ALL", MEMBER_NBR, "$tok_member$") 
and DAY = if("$tok_day$"="ALL", DAY, urldecode("$tok_day$"))
|sort limit=0 CORRELATIONID, DATE_UPDATED asc
```

Comment: It's not helping unfortunately. I have to read more about the comparison I'm trying to make.